# On C++ constructors

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I found the following piece of code in an open source implementation of a game.

```
struct Renderable {
    std::shared_ptr<UniformInput> uniform;
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> geometry;
    bool alpha_blending = true;
    bool depth_test = true;
};


struct ShaderUpdate : Renderable {
    ShaderUpdate(std::shared_ptr<UniformInput> const& uniform)
        : Renderable{uniform, nullptr} {}

    ShaderUpdate(std::shared_ptr<UniformInput> && uniform)
        : Renderable{std::move(uniform), nullptr} {}
};
```

`ShaderUpdate` inherits from 'Renderable' and calls its base class constructor during object creation. But 'Renderable' does not have a 2-parameter constructor defined. Does the presence of "intialized" values in the struct have something to do with this?

Comment: The use of curly brackets rather than parentheses is significant. Search for "uniform initialization".

Comment: In other words, it is perfectly fine that `Renderable` does not have a 2-parameter constructor defined, or any constructor for that matter, because `ShaderUpdate` is not invoking any constructor of `Renderable`.  Curly braces do ***not*** denote invocation of constructors.

Comment: It took a while wrapping my head around this. Initializer lists in this form is known as [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Such a construct feels iffy though... I'd prefer defining appropriate constructors instead of doing this. 

@molbdnilo,  MikeNakis Would you recommend it? I read that this solved ambiguities wrt to initialization in the pre-C++11 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what's going on here is that the Renderable is getting default constructed and then the values of uniform and geometry are being set. The compiler generates the default constructor and then you are just setting the values. I guess you are using c++14/11 or higher otherwise this won't even work since older c++ versions don't allow this.